# NSString to NSArray and iterate

Tags: xcode, nsarray

I have a code that creates an NSString and separates value with a comma. What I need to do is take that string, convert it to a NSArray and separate each value from the NSString between the commas, then iterate through each one. The code below returns the array as a single string

```
NSString *emails = @"testemail@gmail.com, testemail2@gmail.com";
NSArray *listItems = [emails componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
for (int i = 0; i < [listItems count]; i++) {
    NSString *address = (NSString*) [listItems objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog (@"ADDRESS: %@", address);
```

The Log shows the response testemail@gmail.com, testemail2@gmail.com when I want it to separate each one individually. Should this be an NSMutableArray instead?

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. You'll get two (separate) lines starting with ADDRESS:

But nowadays (actually since 2009!) it's highly recommended to use *Fast Enumeration* if the loop index is not needed

```
NSString *emails = @"testemail@gmail.com, testemail2@gmail.com";
NSArray *listItems = [emails componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
for (NSString *email in listItems) {
    NSLog(@"ADDRESS: %@", email);
}
```

Comment: I tried that too but it still doesn't separate each item. I am still getting the value of the email as testemail@gmail.com, testemail2@gmail.com. Basically I need to send individual emails with each value in the email string but it only sends one email.

Comment: Then your code is not the real code. The given code in the question  **does** separate the items.